# How do I change default directory and index file for Apache (installed via XAMPP)

Tags: apache, file, directory, xampp, default

How do I change default Directory and index File for Apache (installed via XAMPP) so instead of looking for `htdocs` and `index`, it looks for `myPath` and `myFile`, respectively?

Comment: After you make any edits to httpd.conf or any other configuration file (php.ini etc) you'll have to restart Apache to see the changes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The research link you pasted has the first part of the answer to your question, changing the path you want serve but the second part of your question, making it serve "myFile" as the Index is an additional step. See:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

So you would add this line inside the relevant   tags or even loose in the main httpd.conf file (see the Context section of the above link for valid places to use this directive):

```
DirectoryIndex myFile.ext
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the httpd.conf file - the DocumentRoot directory can be updated to whichever directory you would like (and that the process has permissions to).  See:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot

```
DocumentRoot /usr/web
```

Comment: Thanks - better site.  What about the defualt file?  This is separate from the DocumentRoot Directive?

Comment: The default file in a vanilla Apache setup is typically the one titled 'index' (the DirectoryIndex hint above) and yes, it is separate from the DirectoryRoot directive.  The bad news - applying the DirectoryIndex changes the default for _every_ directory.  The way to get around that, perhaps, is writing an .htaccess file to rewrite/redirect the 'index' URL to your file.