# How to open a html file by default in my browser when i type the relevant url using apache?

Tags: apache, xubuntu

I know this may be long but please bear with me..

I am using Xubuntu. I have installed apache 2.something(I think it is 2.4) using sudo install from commandline. Inside my File System folder there is var folder inside of which there is www folder inside of which there is hello folder which contains a spring mvc application made by me **named Fitness Tracker**.

So basically the folder structure is (**FileSystem/www/hello/FitnessTracker**).The root folder is encrypted so all the folder had to be created at someplace at first and then through command line using sudo all were transferred to www/hello.Fitness Tracker has a html page inside it named **hellothere.html**.

Now when i start apache server from command line and then type following url in my browser **localhost/hello/FitnessTracker** . I get a directory structure of FitnessTracker meaning it shows the html file and the other subfolders FitnessTracker contains. Now my requirement is when **localhost/hello/FitnessTracker** is typed in address bar of browser, I have to open **hellothere.html** page. How can this be done??

P.S. I have already placed a virtual host file inside my sites-available directory which contains the following code

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName east.example.org
 DocumentRoot /var/www/hello/FitnessTracker
<Directory /var/www/hello/FitnessTracker>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here for my code **localhost/hello/FitnessTracker** and **http://east.example.org**/ calls are synonomous which means both of them return the directory structure.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6077322/1847340

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `DirectoryIndex hellothere.html` to your vhost config.

Also placing in sites-available won't be enough for you to use the vhost, it needs to be sym-linked in sites-enabled, or run `sudo a2ensite mysite` and `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: Thanks @RaggaMuffin-420 for the answer. One more question if my Fitness Tracker application contains another subdirectory inside of which there is a jsp folder within which there is a file named hello.jsp. What must be done so that hello.jsp may appear when i type east.example.org . P.S I have already tried adding DirectoryIndex hello.jsp but it didn't work.

Comment: You have to set your DocumentRoot to that directory, and set the DirectoryIndex to hello.jsp then it will load.  if you want to preserve the localhost/hello/FitnessTracker  then you will have to create a new virtualhost for your localhost.

Comment: Oh it worked thanks @RaggaMuffin-420 ......i restarted my computer and it worked .....Thanks for the help///:)

Comment: You probably only need to restart apache.. not your computer.